# Save camera input as GIF in ActionScript 3

Tags: flash, actionscript, gif

I want to create an animated gif about 15 seconds long directly from the camera's input.

At the moment I've done this by taking images every few milliseconds and I plan on processing these images server-side using something like ffmpeg to create a final gif.

Is there a way to have flash do the whole thing?

Answer (score 1):

There's a gif library to do this. I'm not terribly sure how it works, but looking at the API it seems as though it's something like:

```
var encoder:GIFEncoder = new GIFEncoder();

encoder.start();
encoder.addFrame(bitmapData); // for each frame
encoder.finish();
```

https://github.com/audreyt/as3gif

**Update**

I was able to encode to gif using the following function, which takes an Array of BitmapData and returns a ByteArray.

```
public function encode(frames:Array):ByteArray
{
    var encoder:GIFEncoder = new GIFEncoder();

    encoder.start();

    for (var i:int = 0; i < frames.length; i++)
    {
        encoder.addFrame(frames[i]);
    }

    encoder.finish();

    return encoder.stream;
}
```

Comment: i saw this lib- but it looks like it does it frame by frame on the timeline. i wasnt really thinking of doing it that way (on the timeline).

Comment: I think the start/finish methods are just writing header/footer info. I'm pretty sure you could just run this at the end and iteratively add all the frames, ie: `for each (var frame:BitmapData in yourframes) encoder.addFrame(frame)`. It seems to output everything to a byte array that you can access to write to a file or upload/etc.

Comment: I've been messing with this awhile.  i think i found some samples that look like they do the job.   but the problem im having is saving the gif to disk.

it doesnt look like i can paste  a lot here. 
but what i have is something like this.
var snapshot:BitmapData=new BitmapData(video.width, video.height);
var bitmap_mc:MovieClip = new MovieClip();
var bm:Bitmap=new Bitmap(snapshot);
bitmap_mc.addChild(bm);
var animationEncoder:GIFEncoder = new GIFEncoder();
for(var c:int = 1 ; c < bitmap_mc.length ; c+{animationEncoder.addFrame(bitmap_mc[c]);}
   animationEncoder.finish();

Comment: basically fs.writeBytes(ba); with var ba:ByteArray = animationEncoder.encode(bitmap_mc);  is no dice.   i return error reference with static type org.bytearray.gif.encoder:GIFEncoder.

Comment: Let me take a closer look at the library and I'll get back to you :)

Comment: I've updated the function in the question answer and have verified that this works for me. In the code you provided in the comments, you did not have an animationEncoder.start(); perhaps this was the issue?